# Using observableLists in a division formula and receiving an error

Tags: java

I am working on a program that is a tip calculator. i am using a observable list to store the item as a string, the items price as a double and an observable list. so it would pull the items price from the list and then i can use it in the formula to do the calculations. i havent worked much with observable lists so im learning about them but from the references ive been looking at im unsure why i am getting the error i am...

the error i get it "bad operand types for '/' first type:ObservableList second type: double

i dont get why if the data types match i cant use this

currently my formula i am trying to use for converting the percent to decimal is:

```
//to convert tip percent to decimal number to be used in equation
   double tipPercentC= price/=100.0;
```

my observable lists are

```
 //observable list for items
private ObservableList<String> items;
private ObservableList<Double> price;
private ObservableList<Order> orders;
```

this makes them, my partner did this portion

```
/**
     * Instantiates 10 objects
     */
    Order order1 = new Order("Pizza", 23);
    Order order2 = new Order("Sandwich", 13); 
    Order order3 = new Order("Caserole", 15);
    Order order4 = new Order("Salmon", 20);
    Order order5 = new Order("Pie", 10);
    Order order6 = new Order("Combo Meal", 25);
    Order order7 = new Order("Steak", 35);
    Order order8 = new Order("Ramen", 36);
    Order order9 = new Order("Pasta", 30);
    Order order10 = new Order("Sushi", 45);

   /**
    * Instantiates and gets all the orders
    */


     items = FXCollections.observableArrayList( order1.getItem(), 
            order2.getItem(), order3.getItem(),order4.getItem(), 
            order5.getItem(), order6.getItem(), order7.getItem(), 
            order8.getItem(), order9.getItem(), order10.getItem() );

    orders = FXCollections.observableArrayList(order1, order2, order3, order4, 
            order5, order6, order7, order8, order9, order10); 



    price = FXCollections.observableArrayList(order1.getPrice(), order2.getPrice(), order3.getPrice(),
      order4.getPrice(), order5.getPrice(), order6.getPrice(), order7.getPrice(), order8.getPrice(), order9.getPrice(), order10.getPrice());
```

we have another class which is the order class which has the sets and gets that are used for the lists, this is the class

```
package tipcalculator;

/**
 *
 * @author Rohit, Carmine
 */
public class Order {
   String item;
   double price;

/**
 * Default Constructor for Order empty constructor
 */
public Order(){
this("", 0);
}
/**
 * 
 * @param item
 * @param price 
 */
public Order(String item, double price){
setItem(item);
setPrice(price);        

}


/**
 * set items 
 * @param item 
 */
public void setItem(String item){
    this.item = item;
}
/**
 * double price greater than 0
 * @param price 
 */
public void setPrice(double price){
    if (price > 0){
        this.price = price;
    }
}
/**
 * 
 * @return items
 */
public String getItem(){
    return item;
}
/**
 * 
 * @return 
 */
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
}
```

im comfortable doing the math im just unsure why im receiving the error i am

Comment: also now getting the same error when i try multiplying using '*'...

Comment: Why do you need multiple lists when you have all information in one list (`orders`) and where is the code that generates the error?